# How to make flat spirals

Tags: modeling, mesh

What would be the most efficient way to make a spiral curve for objects shaped as in the photo?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may do it using *Spirals* of the ***Curve Extra Objects*** add on.
[image]

Activate the add on in *User Preferences*-->*Add-ons* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Add a *spiral* and play with its settings (*Spirals* panel in a *Tool Shelf*).
[image]
[image]

Extend the spiral's lenght extruding the curve's points. Add a *Bezier Circle* in the same position as the *spiral* is. Scale it to give a *curve* a desired thickness. Apply its transformations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Rot&Scale*).
[image]

Select the *spiral* in *Object Mode*, go to the *Curve Data* header and set the *Bezier Circle* as a target of the beveled object.
[image]

Select the very top point of the curve, enable *proportional editing* and translate it along Z axis a bit to hide the ugly end of a *curve*.
[image]

You should get something like this:
[image]

To make make it gradually thinner in the inside select the very top point of the *curve* and scale it a bit with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> using the *proportional editing*. Then scale it with <kbd>S</kbd> with a big proportional size falloff.
[image]

You may also use the *proportional editing* to easy change the curve's height.
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to make it gradually thinner in the inside?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check it out to see how to do it. Thanks for pointing it out btw.

Answer (score -1):

I'd believe using a curve and a bevel object would yield the expected result.

You may change the radius to make it thinner or thicker

Comment: Could you expand your answer? Maybe add some screenshots? How make it thinner in the inside?