# How to make screw spiral down into a point?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

Is there a way to make a screw like object spiral down into a point?  Basically I want a screw modifier on an object and as it spirals it gets smaller and tighter until it makes a point.

Comment: Hi, you could try adding a lattice modifer after screw, and use the lattice to scale it on one side (until it makes a point)

Comment: Please place a Blender screen capture to clarify your question.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79764/how-to-make-flat-spirals

Answer (score 4):

**Curve Modifier. Proportional Edit. Shape Keys.**

[image]

Image above

- Yellow Cylinder. High Density of Vertices is shown with the wire mesh detail on extreme left.
- Blue elongated cone mesh created with proportional edit of Yellow. Vanishing Point on End. Shape Keys.
- Spiral Curve and Blue Mesh with Objects centers in the same location.
- Curve Modifier Shown. With the cone shape dominant.
- Curve Modifier Shown. With Cylinder shape dominant.
- Apply Scale to Curve.
- Please research further for the Curve Modifier. This is just to launch your further research and not a tutorial.  Search here at BSE.

Answer (score 2):

**Proportional Edit your final product after applying other modifiers.**

[image]

- Proportional Edit shown in Blue, Scaled XY with Cursor Pivot.
- Note the rotation scale mode is set to cursor and cursor is placed carefully.
- No effort was taken for Artistry
- Please improve and suit to taste
- I prefer the Curve Modifier answer.  Greatly.