# Modeling gas lamp pipes

Tags: modeling

I am in a bit of a pickle at the moment, as I can't seem to make those tubes look how they should. I tried extruding from the bottom part of the lamp to try and create a curved tube but it just doesn't look right. Any ideas?

[image]

Clearer reference:

[image]

Comment: Cylinder with Proportional Edit.  Curve Modifier.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87072/how-to-make-screw-spiral-down-into-a-point/87076#87076

Answer (score 2):

Create a profile with a Bezier Curve.In Object Mode > SHIFT + "A"> Curve > Bezier.

[image]

Then in the Object Panel > Convert to Mesh from Curve *(Need to be in Object Mode).

[image]

Tab into Edit Mode select all of the vertices by pressing "A" then extrude by pressing "E" and then the letter of the axis you want to extrude in. For me it was "X" "Z".

[image]

Place your cursor here and press ALT +"R". You can adjust the angle Before you do anything else.

[image]

Repeat for the bottom changing the angle to a negative value.

[image]

I believe in real life those are tapered. Select the top ring of vertices and go into Proportional Edit Mode and scale to taste. I used Linear Falloff.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Just the little protuding hole**

Mesh LoopTools is an Addon which must be installed

Simplified form mesh

[image]

Stages of editing left to right top to bottom.  Edit Mode.

- Yellow vertex dense cylinder
- Blue Partial quad strip extrusion
- Yellow Loop Cuts for local vertex density
- Blue Two Patches cut out in square on both sides.  Bridge Edge Loops
- Yellow Mesh Loop Tool changes rectangle hole to circular hole
- Blue Proportional Editing for edge protrusion
- Please improve this to suit you needs
- Technique only. No artistry focus.