# How can I uniformly modify a pipe with coding?

Tags: python, modeling, bones, shape-keys, geometry

I have a plain pipe with a center-line. I need to gradually decrease its diameter towards the end (to create a taper). I've been told that I should use some codes to scale the bones automatically. I would be grateful if anyone could kindly help me with this question.

This is actually a practice. The main task is to modify a 3D model of a vessel (which is more complex) using blender.

Thank you very much.

Mohammadreza

Comment: You do not need Python programming language for this.  I assume you are referring to Python by the word Coding.  Are you?

Comment: Please show your current work for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you need nothing more than a proportional edit, set to 'Linear' profile, and in 'Connected' mode.

With Median Point as your pivot, select an edge loop at one end of your pipe. The extent of the scaling along normals (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) will depend not on the geometric distance from your selection, but on the topological distance (the total edge-length from your selection).. so it works round corners, linearly tapering as you go.

The circle in the 3D view may no longer be a visual indicator of extent - just keep growing it until you begin to see the influence at the other end of your pipe.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Please see

[How to make screw spiral down into a point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87072/how-to-make-screw-spiral-down-into-a-point/87076#87076)

- You may start with a cylinder with respectable vertex density. The more shapely the desired product the more density is required. See image above of cylinder in wire display.  Then edit with Proportional Edit.  Consider Shape Keys.
  Then use use a [Curve modifier].
- You may also consider a [Skin Modifier]