# add curve: extra object does not have spirals

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a flat spiral, and so I looked it up on google which I found this post:
[How to make flat spirals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79764/how-to-make-flat-spirals)
it is exactly what I'm trying to achieve here, so I followed up with the settings and stuff. after that, I realized that my blender (2.79) does not have the spiral option when I'm checking the curve section. does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that 'Curve Sprials' in your screenshot? Or is that from another version?

Comment: it's a different version, it gives me these:
https://gyazo.com/50c23a5078cd2a89b5ab24b2cb1ff6c0,
https://gyazo.com/dfd2a24bf47b094213036a086642b55d,
https://gyazo.com/578d9873792861b2a23a4d9b21a32727,
https://gyazo.com/f58f0dd74689b68ce1ba8bdbd25760c7.

Comment: Curve Spirals > Archimedean > F9 panel > Radius Growth xxx? I don't know, I'd have to rebuild 2.79...

Comment: can you maybe make a spiral and send a .blend or .obj to me? maybe that'll work.

Comment: It would be better to fix your problem.. what shape spiral would you want? Is that screenshot _your_ menu?

Comment: its the one in the https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79764/how-to-make-flat-spirals. the one where the is like a tiny head thing at the middle of it, that's the one i want.

Answer (score 3):

To make a spiral you need to go to Curve > Curve Spirals > Archimedean
Once you do that, you will have what it appears to be a CLOSE circle.
In order to make the spiral, you need to use the side bar to increase the radius growth and add more turns to it.

[image]

Comment: this works! thank you so much!!

Comment: got any tips for doing this in 2.83?

Comment: @JayStanley to be honest, it's the same, the menu looks different, but it's the same process

Comment: Thanks @Emir. Yeah unfortunately the menu moved and I spent an hour trying to find it in its new inobvious location.